# Localize xtable continued conversion label

Tags: context, extreme-tables

I'm having this setup.

```
\mainlanguage[ru]
\setupfloat[table][default={here,split}]
\setupfloatsplitting[conversion=continued]
```

and a table itself like:

```
\startplacetable[title={Список модулей}]
\startxtable
\startxtablehead[head]
\startxrow
\startxcell Наименование модуля \stopxcell
\startxcell Версия \stopxcell
\stopxrow
\stopxtablehead
\startxtablebody[body]
\startxrow
\startxcell altair \stopxcell
\startxcell 4.2.0 \stopxcell
\stopxrow
\stopxtablebody
\stopxtable
\stopplacetable
```

It works quite well except continued table captions. It's `Таблица 2 (continued) Список модулей`.

I wish to change continued to exact Cyrillic word, like `Продолжение`. Is there some way to do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippets be compilabe, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: @Close-voters: It is a first time poster. Isn't it more welcoming and fair to write a comment than to just vote for closing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question (I do not understand the cyrillic parts), `\setuplabeltext` is the command you look for. I modified your example (it is good to give a complete minimal file, I had to switch the font and also to add several rows in the table), see below.

```
\mainlanguage[ru]

\setupbodyfont[dejavu]

\setuplabeltext[ru][continued={ (Продолжение)}]%Important line, note the space!
\setupfloat[table][default={here,split}]
\setupfloatsplitting[conversion=continued]

\starttext
\startplacetable[title={Список модулей}]
\startxtable
\startxtablehead[head]
\startxrow
\startxcell Наименование модуля \stopxcell
\startxcell Версия \stopxcell
\stopxrow
\stopxtablehead
\startxtablebody[body]
\dorecurse{50}{
\startxrow
\startxcell altair \stopxcell
\startxcell 4.2.0 \stopxcell
\stopxrow
}
\stopxtablebody
\stopxtable
\stopplacetable
\stoptext
```

Result:

[image: Table with continued in cyrillic]

I found out this by looking in `lang-txt.lua` in the distribution. If you look there, you will find that there are more empty slots for Russian. If you know what they should be, you can help by sending an email to the context list with your suggestions.

Comment: I'd be inclined to insert a space before the open paren at the beginning of the "continued" replacement.

Comment: Oh, indeed. I did not even look too closely at the result. I will edit. Thanks!